# How to parallelize crontab executions to increase user base for web app based on mongodb and mysql?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, scalability, cron

I have a symfony based web application that runs on mongodb and mysql backend. The principal of the application is that for each user there is a python script that runs 4-12 times a day on cronjobs and populates the mysql and mongodb databases. The script takes between 1.5 minutes to 2 minutes to execute. At the moment the cronjob runs on sequential basis. That means that the script executes a job and waits for the job to end before executing the next one. The moment my web application has a new user the cronjobs are auto created for a duration of time. With 24 hours in a day I can run a limited number of cronjobs thereby, limited number of users (around 250-300)

What would I need to do if I wanted to host 1000 to a million users on my web application? Can I run my script on multithread basis? That means instead of waiting for a job to finish, launch hundreds of job at the same time. This way I can grow my user base exponentially.

But, what concurrency will mongodb and mysql be able to sustain? how many jobs can I execute parallelly? What system factors do I need to consider to grow my user base? Do I need to add more machines to my application?

Comment: It would be hard to advise much without seeing/understanding your script but have a look at GNU Parallel for easily controlling the degree of parallelism.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for your comment. script is calls an external rest api and processes the data and then stores them in the database. Not much more there. Does that help?

Comment: offcourse the processing involves mongodb reads and writes and then applying of an algorithm, hence, the 2 minute execution time